# Output position of Pointer in string C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, output

The code I have below at the moment outputs the letter H which is in position 0 but I want to know if there is a way to also output not just the letter H but also the pointer position of the letter H.

Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
const char* letterPointer = "Harry"; 
cout << letterPointer[0] << endl
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried `(void*)&letterPointer[0]`?

Comment: Or indeed simply `letterPointer`

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit unclear.  It seems like you might be trying to get an index from an arbitrary pointer.  For example if you had a pointer to _somewhere_ in the string and wanted to know its position.  _e.g._ `char * p = strchr(letterPointer, 'r');` -- in which case you can use pointer arithmetic: `int pos = p - letterPointer;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common technique to cast to `void *` from `char *` for that purpose, as follows:

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(&letterPointer[0]) << endl;
```

By the way, in C++, `string` does NOT mean `char *`, but rather [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).
So this include line is not necessary in your code.

```
#include <string> // You'd probably want to remove this line.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.